# Canny's Roadmap Algorithm

Tags: motion-planning

Where can I find a general implementation of Canny's Roadmap Algorithm(or Silhouette Method) for Robot Motion Planning?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you probably can't. The reason is Canny's follows 3 basic steps.

1. Collect a bunch of points in the environment and connect all the points 
   that have a free path between them
2. Connect start and end to this graph
3. Do some kind of path planner on this graph, e.g., Dijkstra.

So, for different evironments, step 1 takes wildly different forms. In 2D, this might be a visibility graph. In 3D, there isn't really a good algorithm for constructing the graph so you might sample. In higher dimensions, it's even worse.

But, if you are comfortable implementing Dijkstra, then implementing 1 and 2 are pretty close in difficulty. You may have to do this homework assignment on your own.

Comment: The first step which you mentioned is some kind of a roadmap generated in Probabilistic Roadmap Method. But what exactly I am looking for is the construction of Silhouette curves which form the roadmap for Canny's Roadmap Method( Silhouette Method).

Comment: Then I suggest you open a new question with exactly that text and see where that gets you. Nobody could just figure out what step you were having trouble with, and magically understand what specific implementation you were looking for.